# negation of propositional expressions in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new in prolog and I have to make a program that negates propositional expressions.

For example: p implies (q and not(r)) sould be p and (not(q) or r).

If anyone could help me it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write down an inductive defintion of negation with pencil and paper. (hint: base case will be propositional constants and inductive cases will be connectives)
2. Decide a syntax for propositional expressions as a prolog term.
3. For each syntactic cateogry of those prolog terms for propositional expressions, transcribe the rules in 1 as prolog caluse, choosing an appropriate name for the predicate, for instance `negate`. The predicate will be binary where each argment is the negation of the other. The predicate would consist of several (I think one or two) base cases and several more inductive cases.

   `negate( ... , ... ). % base case
   negate( ... , ... ) :- ... . % inductive case
   negate( ... , ... ) :- ... . % inductive case
   ...`